# What kind of certificate to be used to consume web services?

Tags: certificates, web-service, client

I have my own application. My client wants me to use their web service. This web service sends some data to my database. For this, my client wants a certificate from me. In this scenario, what kind of certificate should I provide?

Comment: What do you mean by what kind of certificate? "self signed/CA signed type" ?

Comment: Exactly, in this scenario what kind of certificate I should send to my client? I am not sure from my end. Please advice.

Comment: Well, CA signed is almost always the preferred choice. Self signed will become difficult to maintain

Answer (score 2):

A self signed certificate of sufficient key size (2048 bit) would be fine. You wouldn't need a CA signed certificate as the client can add the certificate to their credential store. Use OpenSSL for the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If the client web services have access to the internet or they have a local CA, then I would suggest that you use CA signed certificates.

Otherwise it is fine to use self signed certificates in your case but it will be a headache especially if the client has multiple web services and you want to update the certificate.

[Here is a comparison of different ways to use certificates in SSL](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/148326/107935)